# Distinguishing context dependent classes in CSS

Tags: css, class, naming-conventions

This is more of a RFC. I have CSS classes that have rules assigned by themselves, like *footer*

```
.footer { border: 1px solid black; }
```

And then I have classes that only have rules assigned as descendants of other classes, like *right*

```
.footer .right { position: absolute; right: 0}
.menu .right { float: right }
```

And I want to be able to distinguish between them on the first look, so I know that I can use *.right* in a new context and I won't collide with already present CSS rules.

I thought of naming the context-independent classes capitalized (*Footer*) but that would mean most classes would be capitalized. Or prefixing the context-dependent classes with a dash, like *-right*. As far as my understanding of the standard goes, this is legal. Do browsers handle this OK?

What do you think would be best? Is this generally a good idea?

**Update:**
The point is to distinguish two kind of classes.

- Kind 1 (e.g. foo) would possible have CSS rules applied to them `.foo { ... }`.
- Kind 2 (e.g. bar) would never have CSS rules applied to them, except as descendants of Kind 1 classes `.foo .bar { ... } /* OK */`, and never `.bar { ... } /* WRONG */`

The question then is: How would you recommend to distinguish classes of Kind 1 and Kind 2.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to add some comments and indentations to your code.  For instance

```
/* Main FOOTER style */
.footer { border: 1px solid black; }

    /* sub FOOTER styles */
    .footer .right { position: absolute; right: 0}
    .menu .right { float: right }
```

Of course, this may not work for you if you have a ton of styles.  You would not want to bloat your `stylesheet`.  But if readability is the main thing...

Also, you should try to avoid naming your styles according to what they do (e.g., `.right`) in case you want to change what they do (e.g., make them left) in the future.

Comment: This indentation is great, I'll really consider adopting it, although this doesn't really solve my problem (my concern is for the time you're in HTML and choosing classes, not when you're in CSS and giving the classes some meaning). Yes, I have tons of code -- code that I'm maintaining and that somebody will maintain after me, that's why conventions matter so much for me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it's a good idea!

I would use `class="footer right"` then use `.footer.right`, but some old browsers won't work with that though.

All browsers handle dashes perfectly. I actually use `.footer` and `footer-right` so you can use then like this way:

HTML

```
<div class="footer footer-right">...</div>
```

CSS

```
.footer { border : 1px solid #000}
.footer-right { position : absolute; right : 0}
.footer a { ... }
.footer-right a { ... }
.menu { ... }
.menu-right { float : right}
```

Comment: To clarify, by "some old browsers", specifically it's only IE6 and below that you need to worry about for this. For my part, I stopped supporting IE6 a long time ago, so I would use multiple classes without worrying.

Comment: Yes, using footer-right would be a solution, but that means much longer class names and duplication (`<div class="footer footer-right">`). What I meant is: make _right_ a standalone class but declare with a convention that it will only ever be used as a descendant of another class in CSS rules: `<div class="footer"><div class="-right">...</div></div>` `.footer .-right { float: right; }`

Comment: Yes, it's longer, but creating an nested element to assign a class to it, is waaay much longer that assigning 2 classes to only one element.
I wouldn't like my HTML to be 100% CSS dependent, don't you think?

Comment: You often need a nested element. Imagine you have different containers and each of them have differently styled title bars. The title bars would be nested elements anyway, and in what I suggest, you could assign to them the _-titlebar_ class without worrying that the style of one will affect the other.

Comment: then you could do...
`.content .titlebar{}`
`.content-right .titlebar{}` and still don't worry about the style overlap

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd do. But the point is that I want to make clear by a naming convention, that there are no CSS rules to `.titlebar` alone.

Comment: That's cool, but watch out, sometimes you'll need something more specific and you'll need to 'break your rules'.
Also consider Page Speed documentation telling us that accessing to only one class ie. `.footer` is way faster than accessing `.footer .right` http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#UseEfficientCSSSelectors